# Cant access hyper-v server

Tags: windows-7, hyper-v

i have a hyper-v server and connecting to it from win 7 machine through hyper-v manager.

but now i can't connect to it any more or even ping it.

error rpc server unavailable unable to establish communication
any idea ?

Comment: Sounds like either your firewall is up or the server has crashed. You would need to log on to your Hyper-V server to check it is running or try connecting from another system to see if the problem is your machine or the Hyper-V Server itself.

Comment: I disabled the firewall, but still cant ping it.

Comment: however i still can work on the virtual servers !!

Answer (score 0):

Download the hvremote.wsf script from here; http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/HVRemote/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=3084

And follow the instructions for use found here: http://blogs.technet.com/b/jhoward/archive/2008/11/14/configure-hyper-v-remote-management-in-seconds.aspx

Hope this helps.